# Python dynamically incrementing sum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a dictionary which gives me the sum from 0 to n/2 and all steps in between. n is an arbitrary even number, chosen to be 10 in this example.

```
n=10

dy = {}

for x in range(0,int(n/2)):
  dy["y{0}".format(x)] = 0

for x in range(1,int(n/2)):
  dy["y{0}".format(x)] += dy["y{0}".format(int(x-1))] + x

print(dy)
```

So y0 = 0, y1 (=0+1) = 1 up to y4 (=0+1+2+3+4) = 10.

Now I need a very similar dictionary which gives the following (brackets not to be included, just to clarify calculation):

y0 = 1, y1 (=2+3) = 5, y2 (3+4+5) = 12, y3 (=4+5+6+7) = 22 and y4 (5+6+7+8+9) = 35.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Note: The calculation should be in principle as similar to the above example as the `+x` is just a placeholder for an element of yet another dictionary in the actual code. So in the code the here called  `+x` actually looks more like `+dgr["gr{0}".format(x)].GetPointY(i)`.

Comment: Start by writing a function that, for example, when given 4, returns a list of numbers [5, 6, 7, 8, 9].

Comment: Can you use numpy?

Comment: `'+'.join(map(str, range(n)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use range to achieve what you want. Try this:

```
n=10

dy = {}

for x in range(0,int(n/2)):
    dy["y{0}".format(x)] = 0

for x in range(0,int(n/2)):
    # Just change the line below to this: 
    dy["y{0}".format(x)] += sum(range(x+1, 2*x + 2))

print(dy)
```

Output:

```
{'y0': 1, 'y1': 5, 'y2': 12, 'y3': 22, 'y4': 35}
```

Comment: I've just added a Note to the original post but to my understanding your solution should still work when substituting the two x's in range() by my reference to the ```dgr``` dictionary, right? Furthermore: your code gives 'y0': 0 instead of 1

Comment: Yes, you should get the same output for a similar code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the objective correctly then one way could be:

```
n = 10

def total(num):
    "Helper function to get sum of integers"
    return num * (num +1) // 2

first = {f"y{i}":total(i) for i in range(n//2)}
second = {f"y{i}": total(j)-first[f"y{i}"] for i, j in enumerate(range(1, n, 2))}

# first -> {'y0': 0, 'y1': 1, 'y2': 3, 'y3': 6, 'y4': 10}
# second -> {'y0': 1, 'y1': 5, 'y2': 12, 'y3': 22, 'y4': 35}
```